# Google developer api, max number of projects reached

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-developers-console

Today when i tried creating a new project in the Google Developer console, I got the message that i has exceeded my limit of projects, and that i should request more.

The way i've been going about it till now is to make a new project for each of my customers. I only use the Google Maps Javascript API btw. Am i going about this the wrong way?

Should i instead make a project called "Google Maps" and use the same API key from that project for all my customer websites? None of them are set to any url or site restriction anyways.

Just wondering wether i should suck it up and apply for more, or if i have been doing it wrong all along?

Comment: That sounds to me like you are doing the "right thing" (except that you should have URL/site restrictions on the keys).  If one of your customers starts overrunning the free usage, you can track the usage for that key.  If you use the same key for all the sites, you lose the ability to track them separately and might end up getting charged by Google.  A better option would be to make your customers give you their keys (or register the keys for your customers).

Comment: Would i/we generally be charged for more projects if we're only using stuff like the maps api? If we request more projects that is.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a charge for projects, just for the API usage associated with the project.

Comment: Okay, cool. And thats only if the site has extensive usage of the google product right?